# Not getting response for an api if another api(scheduler) is running

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a node js application with number of api's , in which 2 api's are being called 4 times a day and takes 10 mins to give a response.

In that 10 min duration , if any other api from same application is being called, there is no response output for that api.It just get stuck.

Any idea ?

Comment: Where did I leave my crystal ball?

Comment: __"takes 10 mins"__ ? :(

Comment: try to post the code here.

Comment: 10 mins is because ,it is making heavy box api calls . But what I want to know is why will it affect other api responses .